# Javascript Scrollbar when making a new window?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When I use this code in javascript to make a new window, it creates one, but there is no page scroll bar on the right side. Is there a way to show the scrollbar when creating a new window?

Code used to create new window:

```
window.open('http://www.redlakewalleye.com/promotional/wholesaler-registration-login','_blank','width=400,height=400');
```

Comment: In Chrome there is scrollbars by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollbars must be set manually like this:

```
window.open('http://www.redlakewalleye.com/promotional/wholesaler-registration-login','_blank','scrollbars=1,width=400,height=400');
```

Comment: That looks like what I wanted. Thank you.